# Check box uncheck while scroll up and down in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have one kendo UI grid and I am binding from Javascript below is the code for same.

My issue is when I check the check box and scroll down the grid and scroll up then that checked checkbox is uncheck even I go to next page then also get the same issue.

```
$(gridName).html("");
    var fieldSchema = [];
    var columnSchema = [];

columnSchema.push({
    field: "",
    width: "30px",
    template: "<input id='chkDelete' type='checkbox' />",
});


var counter = 0;
$.each(data, function (index) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    var xmldoc = $.parseXML(data[index].CustomFields);
    var $xml = $(xmldoc);
    var jsonStr = '{';
    $xml.find("Fields").find("Field").each(function () {
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '":{';
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Title":"' + $(this).attr("Title") + '",';
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Value":"' + $(this).attr("Value") + '",';
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Id":"' + $(this).attr("Id") + '"},';

        if (counter == 1) {
            columnSchema.push({
                field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                width: "128px",
                template: "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#",
            });

        }
    });
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"CustomFields":"' + data[index].CustomFields.replace(/\"/g, "\'") + '",';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"ValidationPlanId":"' + data[index].ValidationPlanId + '",';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"IsTrCreated":"' + data[index].IsTrCreated + '",';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Note":"' + data[index].Note + '",';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"IsUpdate":"' + data[index].IsUpdate + '",';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"TestRequestId":"' + data[index].TestRequestId + '"';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '}';

    fieldSchema.push($.parseJSON(jsonStr));
});

var dtVpAdd = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: fieldSchema,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "ValidationPlanId"
        },
        total: function (result) {
            var totalCount = result.length;
            return totalCount;
        }

    }

});
dtVpAdd.pageSize(10);


$(gridName).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: fieldSchema,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ValidationPlanId"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    }),
    columns: columnSchema,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: {
        mode: "multiple",
        allowUnsort: true
    },
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    resizable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false
    },

    dataBound: function () {
        $(gridName).on('click', '#chkDeleteAll', function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            $("input[id*='chkDelete']:checkbox").attr('checked', checked);
        });
    },

});
```

Comment: Checkboxes in a grid are little tricky since you cannot update them (click in the checkbox) without entering in edit mode. Did you keep this in mind? If not, you see the checkbox marked but the model is actually not updated so when you load new data (page, scroll, filter,...) the changes get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes in a `Grid are little tricky since you cannot update them (click in the checkbox) without entering in edit mode.

If you do not take this into account, you see the checkbox marked but the model is actually not updated so when you load new data (page, scroll, filter...) the changes get lost.

One possible solution is define an event handler that when the checkbox is clicked updates the model.

Steps:

Change your template definition to:

```
template: "<input class='ob-checkbox' type='checkbox' #= Checkbox ? 'checked' : '' #/>",
```

Where I specify how to render a checkbox and which is the current value (in this example the value of `Checkbox` field).

Then, define a handler for these `input`. To do so, instead of doing it in `dataBound` I prefer doing it after initializing the `Grid` with a live event handler. Something like:

```
grid.wrapper.on("click", ".ob-checkbox", function(e) {
    // Get the row containing the checkbox
    var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
    // Get the item in the model corresponding to that row
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    // Get current value of the rendered checkbox (not the value in the model)
    var value = this.checked;
    // And update the model
    item.set("Checked", value);
});
```

Where `grid` is defined as:

```
var grid = $(gridName).data("kendoGrid");
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/QubWN/

Comment: If anyone getting issue with below line

item.set("Checked",value); then write below line 

item.Checked = value where "Checked" is your field name.

Comment: Hello OnaBai,
Your solution is working perfect in one grid but when I apply to second grid its not working it giving me below error.

item is undefined. That means "grid.dataItem(row)" is undefined.

please let me know what is the issue with this.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle? Send me the link and I take a look. I've tried and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/QubWN/4/

Comment: var item = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

above code working, Thanks

Comment: @OnaBai - Same issue i am also facing now mine is  kendo tree view grid. I tried as per your code. But in my case it's not working. Please help me to achieve this here is the dojo link http://dojo.telerik.com/uLalo

Comment: @OnaBai please have look my code and give solution. I'm waiting for your reply. Thanks...